# Event Viewer Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/30/2013 10:49:07 AM 
Event time (UTC): 7/30/2013 7:49:07 AM 
Event ID: 3cd75da1805c4998b025fed53ff6bfe0 
Event sequence: 3088743 
Event occurrence: 5 
Event detail code: 0
```

Application information:

```
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/abm-1-130195497240588595 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: /abm 
Application Path: E:\absolutebm\ 
Machine name: DC-IIS-LIVE
```

Process information:

```
Process ID: 11576 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: ALANBA\administrator
```

Exception information:

```
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

Request information:

```
Request URL: http://www.alanba.com.kw/abm/abm.aspx?z=1&m�</a>|</span></li><li id='interli'><a href='/ar/arabic-international-news/'>عربية وعالمية</a><span id='intersp'><label style='padding-right:140px;'> </label><a href='/ar/arabic-international-news/lebanon-news/'>أخبار لبنانية</a>|<a href='/ar/arabic-international-news/egypt-news/'>أخبار مصرية</a>|<a href='/ar/arabic-international-news/syria-news/'>أخبار سورية</a>|<a href='/ar/arabic-international-news/reports-and-issues/'>قضايا وتقارير دولية</a>|</span></li><li id='economyli'><a href='/ar/economy-news/'>اقتصاد وأعمال</a><span id='economysp'><label style='padding-right:230px;'> </label><a href='/ar/economy-news/business-and-markets/'>أسواق وأعمال</a>|<a href='/ar/economy-news/kuwait-stock-exchange/'>بورصة  الكويت</a>|</span></li><li id='sportli'><a href='/ar/sport-news/'>رياضة</a><span id='sportsp'><label style='padding-right:310px;'> </label><a href='/ar/sport-news/arabic-sports/'>رياضة عربية</a>|<a href='/ar/sport-news/world-sports/'>رياضة عالمية</a>|<a href='/ar/sport-news/sports-interviews/'>الو رياضة</a>|</span></li><li id='localli'><a href='/ar/kuwait-community/'>المجتمع</a><span id='localsp'><label style='padding-right:340px;'> </label><a href='/ar/kuwait-community/occasions-events/'>مناسبات</a>|<a href='/ar/kuwait-news/complaints/'>المنطقة الحرة</a>|<a href='/ar/kuwait-news/advertising/'>أخبار اعلانية</a>|<a href='/ar/kuwait-community/exhibitions-and-forums/'>معارض وملتقيات</a>|</span></li><li id='artli'><a href='/ar/art-news/'>فنون</a><span id='artsp'><label style='padding-right:400px;'> </label><a href='/ar/art-news/arabic-international/'>فنون عربية وعالمية</a>|<a href='/ar/art-news/scenes/'>كواليس فنية</a>|<a href='/ar/art-news/remote-control/'>ريموت كونترول </a>|<a href='/ar/art-news/interviews/'>ألو فن</a>|<a href='/ar/art-news/drama-mistakes/'>مبالغات وأخطاء درامية</a>|</span></li><li id='aroundli'><a href='/ar/variety-news/entertainment/'>منوعات</a><span id='aroundsp'><label style='padding-right:440px;'> </label><a href='/ar/variety-news/kitchen-cooking/'>مطبخ</a>|<a href='/ar/variety-news/decor/'>ديكور</a>|<a href='/ar/variety-news/plastic-art/'>فن تشكيلي</a>|<a href='/ar/variety-news/poetry-poems/'>الواحة</a>|<a href='/ar/variety-news/marine/'>بحري</a>|<a href='/ar/variety-news/entertainment/'>تسالي</a>|<a href='/ar/variety-news/life-style/'>أسلوب حياة</a>|</span></li><li id='aworldli'><a href='/ar/world-news/'>حول العالم</a><span id='aworldsp'><label style='padding-right:500px;'> </label><a href='/ar/world-news/technology/'>علوم وتكنولوجيا</a>|<a href='/ar/world-news/tourism-and-travel/'>سياحة وسفر</a>|<a href='/ar/world-news/cars/'>أوتو موتيف</a>|</span></li><li id='opinionli'><a href='/ar/opinion/'>كتاب وآراء</a><span id='opinionsp'><label style='padding-right:635px;'> </label><a href='/customcms/writerlist.aspx'>أرشيف الكتاب</a>|</span></li><li id='editorli'><a href='/ar/exclusive-reports/'>تقارير خاصة</a></li><li id='lastli'><a href='/ar/last/'>الأخيرة</a><span id='lastsp'><label style='padding-right:785px;'> </label><a href='/alwafiyat'>الوفيات</a>|</span></li><li id='aenglishli'><a href='/en/english/'>alanba English</a></li></ul></td></tr></table></span></td></tr>              </table></td>          </tr>        </table></td></tr></table></div><div style= 
Request path: /abm/abm.aspx 
User host address: 213.132.252.179 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: ALANBA\administrator
```

Thread information:

```
Thread ID: 8 
Thread account name: ALANBA\administrator 
Is impersonating: False
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Error seems to be pretty clear. If you're adding that bunch of characters to querystring, you'll need to send them by `POST` instead of `GET` as there is a max length for querystring.

Comment: The error certainly is clearer than the question. ;-)